# Convert MySQL query into prepared statement with possible null value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

In an effort to prevent sql injections, I am converting my queries into prepared statements. I have one left. It contains a possible null value too, hence it's proving to be a little difficult.

Normal:

```
// Declare $dbc, $varA, $varB, $varC, $ID

$varC = ($varC == '-') ? "NULL" : "'" . $varC . "'";

$query = "UPDATE myTable ";
$query .= "SET VARA = '{$varA}', VARB = '{$varB}', VARC = $varC ";
$query .= "WHERE ID = '{$ID}'";

$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Attempt at prepared statement:

```
// Declare $dbc, $varA, $varB, $varC, $ID

$varC = ($varC == '-') ? "NULL" : "'" . $varC . "'";

$query = "UPDATE myTable ";
$query .= "SET VARA = ? VARB = ? VARC = ? ";
$query .= "WHERE ID = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $varA, $varB, $varC, $ID);
$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: As long as the column could be null it should be no problem inserting null.  I wouldn't send in the string "NULL" though (NULL !== "NULL") and you don't have to quote the param like this `"'" . $varC . "'"` - just send in `$varC`

Comment: I tried that way too, but the query doesn't seem to update the DB either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
$varC = ($varC == '-') ? null : $varC;
```

?

Also, you are missing the commas in your query

```
$query .= "SET VARA = ?, VARB = ?, VARC = ? ";
```

**Edit:**
I just ran the code with my changes and it seemed to work okay. For reference, this is the code I used:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$dbc = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "test", "test", "test");


$ID = "1";
$varA = "a";
$varB = "b";
$varC = "-";

$varC = ($varC == '-') ? null : $varC;

$query = "UPDATE myTable ";
$query .= "SET VARA = ?, VARB = ?, VARC = ? ";
$query .= "WHERE ID = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $varA, $varB, $varC, $ID);
$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Could you try adding the error reporting lines to the top of your code and see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: I tried that way too, but the query doesn't seem to update the DB either way.

Comment: @Ali, you have also forgot the commas between all your fields in your SET statement. I'll update my answer to account for that.

Comment: nice catch!, but no change in DB. Is there a way to output the query AFTER it's prepared?

Comment: @Ali I've run the code myself and it seems to work. For reference I've attached what I ran to my original answer. It also has two lines at the top that turn on error reporting. If you add them to your code does it output any errors?

Comment: Maybe it was a cache issue or something, but it appears to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali Cool cool. I'm glad it's working for you now.